# How can i pass one variable from a method to another method using same class?

Tags: django

How can i get variable qid in the 2nd method(form) from 1st method(contect_data).

now i getting error :
     NameError: name 'tmp' is not defined

```
class AnswerView(FormView):
    template_name = 'answer.html'
    form_class = AnsForm
    success_url='success'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AnswerView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qid = self.kwargs['qid']
        print(qid)
        self.qid=qid
        q_obj = Quest.objects.get(id=qid)
        context['question'] = q_obj

        return context

   def form_valid(self, form):

       answ1 = form.cleaned_data['txta']

       tmp = self.get_context_data().qid
       obj4=Ans.objects.create(answer=answ1,status=0,questid=tmp)
       obj4.save()
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use `self.kwargs['qid']` in `form_valid` also. So you can simply do this:

```
class AnswerView(FormView):
    template_name = 'answer.html'
    form_class = AnsForm
    success_url='success'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AnswerView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qid = self.kwargs['qid']
        q_obj = Quest.objects.get(id=qid)
        context['question'] = q_obj

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):

       answ1 = form.cleaned_data['txta']

       tmp = self.kwargs['qid']
       obj4=Ans.objects.create(answer=answ1,status=0,questid=tmp)
       obj4.save()
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be by setting the variable qid as a data member of your class, although I'm not sure if that's ideal for your usecase. That way both the methods can access and modify it. Hope this solves your problem.